# Issue when installing RxReachability via CocoaPods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I would like to install RxReachability onto an app that I'm creating but I keep getting an error message when I try to install it.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "RxSwift":
In snapshot (Podfile.lock): RxSwift (= 4.2.0, ~> 4, ~> 4.0, ~> 4.2.0)

In Podfile:
RxAlamofire was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
  RxAlamofire/Core (= 4.2.0) was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
    RxSwift (~> 4)

RxCocoa was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
  RxSwift (~> 4.0)

RxCoreLocation was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
  RxCoreLocation/Core (= 1.3.0) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
    RxSwift (~> 4.2.0)

RxReachability was resolved to 0.1.0, which depends on
  RxSwift (~> 3.3)

RxSwift
```

This is what's in my podfile:

```
target 'myApp' do
use_frameworks!

  # core RxSwift
  pod 'RxSwift'
  pod 'RxCocoa'
  pod 'RxDataSources'
  pod 'RxReachability'

  # Community projects
  pod 'NSObject+Rx'

  # Data Handling
  pod 'RxAlamofire'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'

  # Location Handling
  pod 'RxCoreLocation'

  # Image handling
  pod 'Kingfisher'
end
```

I've never had an error like this. Can someone help please?

Comment: According to https://github.com/bmoliveira/RxReachability/blob/master/RxReachability.podspec  RxReachability is compatible with RxSwift4. Did you do `pod update`?

Comment: The issue is that you can only have one version of each Pods. Each pod may depends on another one. Apparently you RxReachability depends on the RxSwift 3.3 , while the others depend on 4.0. But there is a RxReachability working with RxSwift 4.0. So you shouldn't get the issue. You can use `pod update` then https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html

Comment: @Larme I've ran pod update already it doesn't fix anything, unfortunately.

Comment: `pod update RxReachability` doesn't update it to 0.1.4?

Comment: @Larme RxReachability doesn't install so it won't update... I've created my own version now. Thanks for trying to help :).